# Run bat file which contains powershell script using php?

Tags: php, powershell, batch-file

I want to run bat file via php.This bat file contains power shell script.I am able to run this via cmd but not via php.

AwsExecute.bat is,

```
powershell -command ./AWSExecuter.ps1
```

This AwsExecuter.ps1 which is inside the C:\AWS\Distributed-setup-3 folder.

In php I have tried like this,

Trail.php which is in http://localhost/performance folder.

```
<?php
            exec('C:\AWS\Distributed-setup-3\AwsExecute.bat'); 
            echo "Done";          
?>
```

As well as,

```
<?php

            exec('c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START C:\AWS\Distributed-setup-3\AwsExecute.bat');

            echo "Done";          
?>
```

Both are not working here, I tried to another bat file which just creates a php file it works fine.

That is First.bat,

```
echo off
break>"C:\Users\Vidya\Desktop\performance.php"
echo done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `system`

```
system("cmd /c C:\AWS\Distributed-setup-3\AwsExecute.bat");
```

For more on `system` [read this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)

Comment: @Vidya What does that mean? it is not working fine? what happens? Errors?

Comment: it is not giving any error.When I run this AwsExecute.bat file it has to create Amezon Webservice instance.when I run this bat file via cmd it is creating the instance.But not via php.

Comment: Do I need to mention any username and password of AWS.If required how?

Comment: Is it possible?

Comment: Can ant body help me .I want to do this one as soon as possible.